# Read and edit value in a MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, settings

I've some trouble when I try to setup my account system in my website. I've used these php files (http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html) but they're too limited! I've try to add some account's settings like (city, age, sex and other).
I'm searching for PHP codes that allow me to add these feautres. I've tried with some PHP code but them don't work.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is vague. Can you explain it a little bit more, with some code snippets maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're in need of a tutorial.

Here are a few;

1. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/user-membership-with-php/
2. http://x10hosting.com/forums/tutorials/93408-tutorial-php-mysql-membership-system.html
3. http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Complete-Members-System/9035

I find tutorials the best way to get something done. I'm guessing you're building some sort of membership system. There's quite a few elements to something like that but if you follow the tutorials it's far easier in the long run.

Comment: I've resolved with the first method. Thank you for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note. This is just an example of the approach you could take.

You'll need to add the columns to your User(s) table.

```
ALTER TABLE `User` 
ADD `city` VARCHAR( 80 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
ADD `date_of_birth` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
ADD `sex` TINYINT( 1 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 = undefined, 1 = male, 2 = female'
```

Note that for gender: 0 = undefined/not given. 1 = Male. 2 = Female.

When creating a new user, use an INSERT SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO `User` (`email`, `etc`, `city`, `date_of_birth`, `sex`) 
VALUES ('Test@test.com', 'Random value', 'London', '1987-04-02', 1);
```

When updating a current user, use an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE `User` SET `city` = 'Dublin', `date_of_birth` = '1987-04-02' 
WHERE `user_id` = 4647
```